# globals and parfor

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, global-variables, parfor

Inside a `parfor` loop, I am trying to call a function that accesses a `global` to no avail.

The function

```
function a = getA()
   global OPTIONS;
   a=OPTIONS.PROBLEM.A;
end
```

The loop:

```
parfor i=1:3
    b=getA();
end
```

The error:

```
Error using parallel_function (line 589)

Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I propose a quick fix without rewriting your entire code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53653710/4262057

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/troubleshoot-variables-in-parfor-loops.html) on `parfor`:

> The body of a parfor-loop cannot contain global or persistent variable declarations.

In the context of your problem, i.e., calling a function within the `parfor` that in turn references a `global`, this translates into: "`parfor` will probably not give expected or meaningful results".

This makes perfect sense. Consider the following

```
Lab 1:         Lab 2: 

GetB();        GetB();
```

if the contents of `GetB()` is this:

```
function GetB()
    global B;

    %# do something useful

    B = rand;

 end
```

what will the value of `B` be when it is referenced on `Lab 1`? and on `Lab 2`? How are the different outcomes of `rand` communicated? It's going to be a mess!

Writing code suited for `parfor` loops can be a real pain when that code comes from something that only had normal `for`-loops in mind. Generally, when you know beforehand you're going to write a computationally intensive piece of Matlab code, write all functions and loops as `parfor` loops right from the beginning. That is the only way that bugs like these will not cost you a day on transcoding your functions.

Converting from `for` to `parfor` is **not at all trivial**.

Comment: Yes, I also saw that - but it is a little ambiguous: Does that mean I cannot even reference existing global variables? the "Declaration" inside getA() is a reference to an existing global variable, not creating a new one. 

And is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @noam see last edit. The easiest fix for this is to un-global the `global` and pass it around as an argument to all functions that need it.

Comment: @noam OK, last edit on this; a bit of background. Hope this helps.

Comment: It is categorically not the case that calling a function within PARFOR that access `global` data is "illegal". However, as you point out, the results are quite likely to be unexpected as the different "global" variables are unconnected.

Comment: @Edric you're right, *illegal* is not true. All global variables loose their "globalness", though.

Comment: Well running MATLAB 7.11.0 on Linux, `global` variables appear to exist (i.e. `exist('x','var')` returns `true`), but may fail to evaluate when you subsequently ask for the value (i.e. `tmp=x` --> `Undefined function or variable 'x'`). It may depend on which thread you are in. Personally I think this is bad behaviour on MATLAB's part...

Comment: Speaking about non-meaningful/unexpected results: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49688601/5211833

Answer (score 6):

`GLOBAL` data is hard to use inside `PARFOR` because each worker is a separate MATLAB process, and global variables are not synchronised from the client (or any other process) to the workers. It would work if you initialized the global data from a separate function on the workers. (As Rody points out, using the `global` keyword *directly in the body of a PARFOR loop* is not allowed - however, separate functions can do this). So, it would be legal to do this:

```
parfor ii=1:matlabpool('size')
  myFcnWhichSetsUpGlobalData(); %# defines global OPTIONS
end
parfor ii=1:N
  result(ii) = myFcnWhichUsesGlobalData(); %# reads global OPTIONS
end
```

I would personally attempt to remove `GLOBAL` data from your application - it will make it work better with `PARFOR`, and it will make dependencies clearer.

One further option to explore is my [Worker Object Wrapper](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31972-worker-object-wrapper) which is designed to stop you having to transfer data to the workers multiple times. You might use it this way:

```
options = buildOptions();
w_options = WorkerObjWrapper(options);
parfor ii=1:N
  result(ii) = myFcnNeedingOptions(ii, w_options.Value);
end
```

Comment: would the global variables for individual workers persist, once the control passes out of the `for` loop containing `myFcnWhichSetsUpGlobalData()` function OR control comes out of the file containing `myFcnWhichSetsUpGlobalData()` ?

Comment: Yes, the global variables on the worker processes continue to work as normal - but they are oblivious to changes made on other worker processes. (Same goes for persistent variables).

Comment: So when do these Glo-Cal variables actually cease to exist? When the `main()` dies ? Also, is there currently a way to access the values of variables local to a worker/processor from client program ?