# matlab global variables and parallel pooling

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, global-variables

I want my script to run faster, so the purpose is, to use my cores simultaneously. The problem is that i somehow miss a layer of globality. I want my globals to be persistent within some functions, but i want them to be different in each loop-call.

what i want to do:

```
 parfor i:T
   createData()     % global variables are being created
   useData()        % several functions need access to global vars
 end
```

I thankful for any idea, to make this loop work simultaneously, subject to keeping my variables global. Thanks for your advise :)

Comment: using global variables in general not recommended as they slow down computational efficiency  unless you really need them. Some discussion can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99537-which-type-of-function-call-provides-better-performance-in-matlab)

Comment: This is impossible. As parfor iterations are executed simultaneously and in any order you simply cannot use global variables in it. You have to change your code to use local variables instead, there is no other way.

Comment: unfortunately, i need the globals to solve a minimization problem. without it the target function doesnt know with respect to what is has to be minimized.

Comment: @Antalagor Generally you can avoid using global variables. But if you can't, then you can;t use paralel coding.

Comment: You can often use anonymous functions (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to add data to functions that you're trying to optimise. Perhaps this would let you avoid `global` data - see also http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue; I was unable to use Global variables within the parallel loop (`parfor` or using `spmd`) as they turned out as empty when triggered.

Instead of rewriting the entire code, I did a quick fix by storing the needed Global variables before the parallel pool and then loading them in the relevant functions if they are empty. In this way I keep my Global variables logic and only load them if they are in a parallel pool.

```
% Store global variables to be reused in parallel workers
global Var1
save('temp_global_parallel','Var1');

% Parallel pool functions
parpool(4)
spmd
    someFunctions();
    anotherFunction();
end

% Optionally: delete to avoid the bug as explained below
delete('temp_global_variable');
```

And then inside the function that uses the Global variable:

```
global Var1
if isempty(Var1)
    load('temp_global_parallel')
end
```

**Caution**: The disadvantage is off course that if the Global variable is really empty, then you would not detect it. You could solve this by deleting the .mat file after the parallel loop.

**Second caution**: I would not recommend storing big variables (in any case do not them as Global variables) as this might lower the speed significantly in each loop. Storing and loading variables is bad practice in general. Instead, try to store only things like constants or some parameters. In my case I was storing a string with the current path extension (which is less than 1kb).